# Cannot import serializers.ListSerializer

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

When trying to use `ListSerializer`, [according to this doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#listserializer), I get an error:

```
Cannot find reference 'ListSerializer' in 'serializers.py'
```

Here is my import statement:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using Django REST Framework 3. The `ListSerializer` was added in DRF 3 and did not exist in earlier version.

You can check this using `pip freeze`, and you should see a line similar to...

```
djangorestframework==3.0
```

...in the the output. If you are using an earlier version, you can upgrade to get the new `ListSerializer`, as well as many other features that were recently introduced.